# How to navigate from drawer navigator to another with nested navigators?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

#### Navigator Structure

-DrawerNavigators
 --TimelineNavigators
   --- Screen1 (initialRoute)
   --- Screen2 
-- SettingsScreen

---

#### TimeLine Navigator

```
export const TimelineNavigators = StackNavigator({
    'screen1': { screen: Timeline, navigationOptions:Screen1NavigatorOptions() },
    'screen2': { screen: LiveMap,  navigationOptions:Screen2NavigatorOptions() },
},{initialRoute: 'screen1'});
```

#### Drawer

```
    const routeConfiguration = {
        'TimelineNavigators': { screen: TimelineNavigation, navigationOptions: timeLineDrawerOptions },
        'SettingsScreen': { screen: SettingsScreen , navigationOptions: settingsDrawerOptions },
    };

    export const NavigatorAuth = DrawerNavigator(routeConfiguration, drawer

Options());
```

#### Setting Screen

```
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

class Settings extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('screen2')}  title="Go to Screen 2"/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Settings;
```

### I click 'Go to Screen 2 ' button , then not go to Screen 2.

#### Current Behavior

When click button (onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Screen2') }) on SettingsScreen, nothing happens. Screen was not changed. is it bug ?

#### Expected Behavior

When click button (onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Screen2') }) on SettingsScreen , have to open Screen2.

#### Environment

| react-navigation | 1.0.0-beta.19
| react-native     | 0.49.5
| node             | 6.11.2
| npm or yarn      | 5.5.1

Comment: I believe it is the expected behavior. To navigate to `screen2` you need to first navigate to `TimelineNavigators` and then `screen2`.

Comment: you are all right. But it is not usable. There is one solution which 
 navigation.navigate('TimelineNavigators'); navigation.navigate('Screen2'). this is not good :/ @bennygenel

Comment: Türkmüşsün kardeş niye türkçe yazmadın @bennygenel :)